# How to 'justify-content: center' for MUI Pagination?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to center the contents of the Pagination. However, this does not work. On console, I need to justify the ul wrapper and I can not find any information on MUI site related to the pagination props or a guide on how to center the item.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Pagination from '@material-ui/lab/Pagination';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '& > *': {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
   
    },
  },
  pagination: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justify: 'center',
  }
}));

const Paginated = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Pagination className={classes.pagination} count={props.totalPage} color='primary' />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Paginated;
```

and I have been trying on codesandbox as well. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-zv1ps?file=/demo.js

Is there any way I can do this without having an additional box or Grid wrapper to wrap it out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
      justifyContent:"center",
      display:'flex'
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and I just tried and it doesn't center :/

Comment: @GIHYUNNAM, check my answer

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. I was missing 'display: flex'!

Comment: Could you please explain what "& > *" does?

Answer (score 11):

We can also use [Stack component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stack/):

```
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';

<Stack alignItems="center">
    <Pagination className={classes.pagination} count={props.totalPage} color='primary' />
</Stack>
```

Answer (score 1):

`margin: "auto"` worked for me

```
root: {
  margin: "auto",
},
```

I got the idea from here: [4 ways to center a component in Material-UI](https://medium.com/@tsubasakondo_36683/4-ways-to-center-a-component-in-material-ui-a4bcafe6688e)

Answer (score 0):

```
<Pagination
  ...
  sx={{
    '& > .MuiPagination-ul': {
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  }}
/>
```